# scrollTop property is not working in react

Tags: reactjs, scrolltop

I am trying to move scroll to top position using this code

```
   function resetScroll(){
        let dropDowns = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown-menu");
            for(let i=0;i< dropDowns.length; i++){
              dropDowns[i].scrollTop = 0;
            }
    }
```

but it does not seem to work.
Can anybody help

Comment: This code should work, can you add the html and the css part?

Comment: <div
                      className="dropdown-menu"
                      aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton"
                    >
                   <div>.....</div>
                <div>

have used bootstrap dropdown menu class

Comment: Actually it only applies for, the drop-down that is open. How to reset about the closed ones.